# Matching network subnets with BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a huge set of object (*i.e. traceroutes*) hosted in Google BigQuery. Those objects can be considered as arrays of IP addresses (called *hops*). I am trying to find a query to identify all the traceroutes crossing a few set of prefixes of interest (*i.e. prefixes_of_interest*). Those prefixes can be found in another dataset hosted in BigQuery as well. I have been able to write a query to discover all the traceroutes crossing a specific set of IP addresses (*i.e. ip_of_interests*), after *start_date* via this query:

```
WITH
  traceroutes AS (
  SELECT
    hops,
    start_time
  FROM
    `traceroute` AS t
  WHERE
    DATE(start_time) >= start_date )
SELECT
  hops,
  h.hop_addr,
  start_time
FROM
  traceroutes,
  UNNEST(hops) AS h
WHERE
  h.hop_addr IN (
  SELECT
    IP
  FROM
    `ip_addresses`)
```

Now, in practice, I could translate all of my prefixes to IP addresses and reiterate a similar query but that feels like a very inefficient way to proceed. I would like to know if there is a way to match the *h.hop_addr* prefixes with the one from my database *prefixes_of_interest*. In practice, my subnetworks have different lengths (most are /24 but I have a few /20) but a solution that would match /24 would do the trick and allow me to save tons of space and processing time I reckon. Hopefully the question makes sense!

Comment: Are the IPs strings? Perhaps just extract substrings to have prefixes (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#substr)? Or you could perhaps convert you IPs to INTs and use upper/lower bounds (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#netipv4_to_int64)?

Comment: @MikeKarp That's an interesting suggestion. The IP addresses are strings of the format x.y.z.t. To match two IP addresses prefixes (/24) is basically identical to match two IP addresses to have identical x.y.z. It becomes more complicated when looking at other subnet lengths. But that's already a progress over what I do. Do you have an idea of how I should modify my query to match the first three part of my IP address? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You could use a regex_extract like this: select REGEXP_EXTRACT(IP, '^([0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3})')